# CMS Trends - Custom Vs Prebuilt

Tags: content-management-system

I was trying to analyze the trend about companies leaving their own custom built solution in favor of the standard CMS solutions such as Drupal, Joomla and DotNetNuke etc. While I can find many stories about medium and large organizations leaving their custom solution for Drupal/Joomla etc, I cannot find any reference where organizations are leaving prebuilt CMS's/Frameworks to go custom again. Is this not happening at all or it's just a matter of not being properly documented?

Thank you.

Imran.

Comment: Not sure why you'd leave out SharePoint when discussing what actual corporations are using as a CMS solution.  It has a much higher market penetration than all the products you've described combined.

Comment: Well as per my understanding, SharePoint does not really come in the same realm as other solutions that I have mentioned. SharePoint does, however, allows you to create a CMS very easily on top of it.

Comment: Analysing what trends? What reports are you reading?

Comment: It's just that I was managing different Drupal projects at my company and came across reports about many large organizations opting to use Drupal instead of their own custom solution. The latest big name is Economist. The Economist are ditching their ColdFusion based homegrown CMS in favour of Drupal. Yahoo Research website is also Drupal based and so is all of Sony's websites for its artists.

That got me thinking that is the traffic flowing one way only? Are their any big names that are ditching open-source or commercial CMS's in favour of their own homegrown ones?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a situation where a company has abandoned an in-house developed CMS in favor of re-developing a CMS on their own.

Everything I'm familiar with involves leaving a hand rolled CMS solution in favor of a commercial/open source solution.

Answer (score 0):

Well i can imagine that while most companies prefer homebrewn solutions for some of them or in certain scenario's an open source or commercial alternative might fill their needs.

In case we at our work need to set up a blog we'll most likely choose wordpress, we know it, it does what it needs to do and does it good. Customization isn't a big deal but out of the box it works too.

For larger projects we always use our own CSM built with our own framework, that is what we know best.

So to answer your question, I still have to see the first company going from existing CMS to custom built but i'm fairly certain there are alot doing both.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it just from an engineering standpoint -- a commercial CMS company, with 50 full time engineers, puts in about 100k hours of engineering effort annually into managing and developing products. A homegrown solution typically has a small team of engineers assigned to manage and develop it, often also balancing other projects & responsibilities. Let's say the homegrown solution has a team of 4 people, working part time (20 hours) a week, which is about 4k hours annually into managing and developing the product.

That's **100k vs 4k** hours of engineering in 1 year.

Also consider, for the homegrown solution, most of the first year's **4k hours** will be spent recreating **basic content management** that has been written 100 times over, e.g. permissioning, workflow, approval processes, etc.

From a business standpoint, businesses want to focus on their core competencies. Unless your core competency is content management, makes no sense to build a homegrown CMS from scratch, and companies largely are not doing this, or moving away from them if they have in the past.